# How do I generate a random number between 0.04 and 0.11 in C++?

Tags: c++

If `5 + rand() % 6` generates a random number from 5 to 10, how would I generate a decimal number? I tried assigning a float variable to `((4 + rand() % 8) / 100)`, but that does not do anything except assign the variable to zero.

Comment: Try `((4 + rand() % 8) / 100.0)`. Lookup integer division.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd go with something a little more robust than `rand()` (but that might be because I'm doing research in areas that require high-quality random numbers):

```
#include <random>

double randomDouble(double bottom, double top) {
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(bottom, top);
    std::mt19937 gen; // Mersenne Twister PRNG

    return dist(gen);
}
```

This little function uses a [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister), a common type of PRNG that has a period (number of random numbers before you get repetition) of 2^19937 - hence the name. Now just call it like this:

```
double foo = randomDouble(0.04, 0.11);
```

Comment: Hmmm. I have some doubts this was actually in quesiton.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I answered the question as asked - how to generate a random number between 0.04 and 0.11 in C++. I'd argue that, from a code quality point of view, this is a superior solution to generating a number using `rand()` and then multiplying and dividing it. Plus, if the implementation of `rand()` is as bad as I remember, this'll generate better random numbers to boot.

Comment: We need quality questions in st place. Not meant your answer is bad (besides encouraging asking low quality questions).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: No argument with you there.

Comment: Most of us are intelligent enough to extrapolate on poor quality stuff. That doesn't mean to answer is the correct reaction. Switch to the long term view if questions will be useful for future research or not.

Comment: +1 This is the only answer that steers the questioner away from the modulo operator.  Using modulo is bad with random numbers as it takes the low order bits which for many random number generators (eg LCGs) are much less random (ie shorter period) than the high order bits.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways to transform a number generator `rand()` that produces numbers in `[0, RAND_MAX]` range to make it produce numbers in range `[a, b]`:

1. `n = rand() % (b - a + 1) + a;`
2. `n = rand() * (b - a + 1) / (RAND_MAX + 1) + a;`

The second method is applicable to ranges with non-integer `a` and `b`.

Keep in mind though that aside from the already mentioned random number quality issues, this generator might not produce sufficiently dense coverage of the target range. The greater the value of `RAND_MAX`, the denser is the coverage.